# Where O(n^2) comes from in O(n^2 * log n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

Can you please explain what O(n^2 * log n) can look like? I do understand **O(n * log n)** :

```
s=0
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (j=1; j<n; j *= 2)
    {
        s=s+i*j;
    }

    s=s+1
}
```

when outer loop runs from 1 to n is O(n) and the inner loop  repeats log(n) times per outer loop e.g j *= 2. Also I do understand what **O(n^2)** does (performance is directly proportional to the square of the size of the input data e.g)

```
s=0
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        s=s+i*j;
    }

    s=s+1
}
```

but what is **O(n^2 * log n)**? Can you please give an example.

Comment: Just add another outer loop from 0 to n to your first example. That's n * n * log n = n^2 * log n.

Comment: Or change `for(i=0;i<n; i++)` to `for(i=0; i<n*n; i++)`.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you

Comment: Your first code is not O(n * logn) but O(infinity) because the inner loop never terminates (`j` never changes from 0). You'd need to start `j` from 1 to fix it.

Comment: @interjay Thank you for explaining it to me, I've also edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add one for loop on the outside. That makes it **O(n^2 * log n)** because you repeat **O(n * log n)** **n-times**.

```
for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    s=0
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j *= 2)
        {
            s=s+i*j;
        }

        s=s+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int ij = 0; ij < n; ++ik) {
        for (j=0; j < ij; j *= 2)
        {
            s=s+i*j;
        }
    }
    s=s+1
}
```

Think about it like this:

1. My input is n.
2. In first loop I'm traversing each element from`n`, so my complexity is `n`
3. So it means that in second loop i'm traversing each element `ij` `n` times, my complexity becomes `n*n`
4. In third loop I'm doing logaritmic traversal which visits `logn` elements. But each logaritmic traversal is executed `n*n` times from previous loops, so it becomes `n*n*logn`